# Spark Cassandra integration not using C* optimizations

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spark-cassandra-connector

I am running code from intellij IDE .My spark cassandra cluster has 3 nodes . Cassandra nodes and spark workers are on same machines

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
                  .set(s"spark.sql.catalog.mycatalog", "com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraCatalog")
                  .set("spark.sql.extensions", "com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions")
                  .set("spark.sql.catalog.casscatalog", "com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraCatalog");
val sc = SparkSession.builder()
             .config(sparkConf)
             .master("spark://master")
             .withExtensions(new CassandraSparkExtensions)
             .getOrCreate();
val table = sc.sql("select * from table  where primarykeyA = 1");
table.show(10)
```

Now above query when I run normally will be in millisec as I have mentioned partition key

**Expectation** This query should only hit 1 of worker nodes which has the parition data and should return

Somehow when this runs it ends up going to all worker nodes which indicates Datastax optimization are not in place

Is there a way I can submit below parameter --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.0.0-beta via code

Comment: what `table.explain` shows?

Comment: Issue is when i run on normal spark it dosent distribute keys to each worker node. Howeer when i run same from cassandra node spark it does.

Comment: If you can point me to spark-cassandra how it should be setup .IN my case spark is on machine A,B,C with cassandra , spark master and driver are on machine D.i m running it in client mode (not cluster).. I am not very sure how do I validate my setup paritions are locally getting fetched

Comment: I need to look to internals

Comment: Sure thanks . It would be helpful for me to design my cluster . I am bit hesitant to run spark on Cassandra nodes as analytics workload may vary and would need to scale spark cluster accordingly

Comment: can you still generate the `table.explain`?